# In R: Create an XML header file

Tags: xml, r

How do I create an XML header file in R?  I need to create an xml file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nodeName data="Hello" info="World"/>
```

Right now I am using this code:

```
top = newXMLNode("nodeName",attrs = c(data="Hello" ,info="World"))
saveXML(top,filepath)
```

To produce this:

```
<nodeName data="Hello" info="World"/>
```

How do I get the xml header info to be created with it?

Comment: Look at the prefix argument in [saveXML](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/XML/docs/saveXML).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to create an XML document, not just an XML node. Try

```
doc <- newXMLDoc()
root <- newXMLNode("nodeName",
    attrs = c(data="Hello" ,info="World"), 
    doc=doc)
saveXML(doc, filepath, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  It only produced this though <?xml version="1.0"?>.  How do I get the encoding to appear as well?

Comment: Ugh, staring right at me in the documentation.  Thanks!